# Retrieving separate info from a namles object

Tags: javascript, object

so im getting a list with information from a api, but the api only sends back a object with lots of objects inside, and im wondering if its posible to get the information from the object in the object. how do i make a path?

```
var info = {
  {
    name : "Jeff",
    id : 001
  },
  {
    name : "Oskar",
    id : 002
  },
  {
    name : "Nick",
    id : 003
  }
}
```

And if i want to push the names in to a array, how would i do it?

Comment: You mean like getting "Jeff" when looking for id 001?

Comment: yes, thats what i mean

Comment: The code example you posted is incorrect JavaScript syntax. Are you sure it's not an array?

Comment: shouldnt the name and id keys be wrapped with a parent key of sorts ?

Comment: i read the orginal code wrong, it was a array and not a object :/, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `map` the existing array of objects to a new array with just the names.

```
let result = info.map(a => a.name);
```

More info on [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```js
var info = [
  {
    name : "Jeff",
    id : 001
  },
  {
    name : "Oskar",
    id : 002
  },
  {
    name : "Nick",
    id : 003
  }
];

let result = info.map(a => a.name);
console.log(result)
```